# Bar Chart Color Key is Incorrect

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, data-visualization

Using pandas in jupyter notebook, I'm generating a bar plot of an Interaction Score for the sample Motions colored by the classification of that Motion. The classifications are VS, SUB, OBV, VO, & CTRL. Thus, I use this code for the plot:

```
colors = {'VS':'blue', 
          'SUB':'green',
          'OBV': 'orange',
          'VO': 'red',
          'CTRL': 'black'}


cat_data.sort_values('Interaction_rounded').plot.bar(x='Motion',
                                               y='Interaction_rounded',
                                               rot=90,
                                               title='All Motions Interaction Score Colored by Classification',
                                               color = [colors[i] for i in cat_data['Classification']],
                                               fontsize = 8,
                                               legend = False)
```

But I get this chart:

[image]

You guys see how CTRL, which is supposed to be **black**, isn't? Same with Fist Swipe, which **is not** supposed to be black. Does anybody know what I can do to correct this?

Comment: Well you sort the data for the plot call, but not the colors, so my guess is you need something like `[colors[i] for i in cat_data.sort_values('Interaction_rounded')['Classification']]` or better sort once before you plot...

Comment: Wow that was exactly it! I didn't know I also had to sort the data for the colors. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I do:

1. pre-compute your colors as a column in the dataframe,
2. sort the entire dataframe, and
3. pipe that copy of the dataframe to a plotting function that can access the newly sorted data:

```py
colors = {'VS':'blue', 
          'SUB':'green',
          'OBV': 'orange',
          'VO': 'red',
          'CTRL': 'black'}


_ = (
    cat_data
        .sort_values('Interaction_rounded')
        .assign(colors=lambda df: df['Classification'].map(colors)
        .pipe(lambda df: 
            df.plot.bar(
                x='Motion',
                y='Interaction_rounded',
                rot=90,
                title='All Motions Interaction Score Colored by Classification',
                color=df['colors'], # now you can access the latest version of the dataframe
                fontsize=8,
                legend=False
            )
        )
)
```

Comment: Wow this is definitely what I'll do next time to simplify and streamline the process. Thanks very much Paul.